# Valid Cypher query without running it in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here, by validating, I mean:
- valid: return records 
- not valid: no records returned by the query

Is there a built-in function inside neo4j so that I can quickly valid the query without running it. for example, something like schema checking.

**What I want to do**
quickly valid lots of queries, so that I can get the queries with results. The problem with running all of the queries is that some query can take lots of time to run, which would block the running of some following queries.

**Temporary solution**
One way I find out is by using `LIMIT 1`　at the end of the query, it's could be much fast than the one without it when there is lots of records, but still the query is run inside the neo4j database

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The only way to see if your query will return anything is to actually run it. But you do not have to run it on your actual ("main") DB.

You can run your query against a smaller test DB whose data model matches the one in your main DB. And you can also tailor the test data so that you know ahead of time what your query should return.

To make this easier, the [Neo4j Desktop](https://neo4j.com/download/) conveniently allows you to create multiple "projects", each with its own DB.

[EDITED]

To make this process a bit more automated, you should take a look at [this example of using APOC procedures to export/import a DB subset](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_roundtrip_example). In your case, you would export from your main DB and import into an empty DB. That example's Cypher code randomly picks a limited number of nodes and relationships to copy, but you may want to use more sophisticated Cypher code to ensure you get the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it's a cool idea. Then a next step question, is there a way to automatically create this kind of test database? Since the problem with our main database is that we don't assume its schema is static, it could change all the time. If that is the case, the test database should be automatically updated when there is a change in the main database.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to [prepend your queries with `EXPLAIN`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) and execute that query. `EXPLAIN` is used to generate the execution plan for a query, but will also result in metadata by comparing your query to the database statistics. For example, if your query contains a Node Label that is not found in the database a warning will be returned in the metadata. The execution plan will also include estimate rows to be returned at each operation.

You can see all of this metadata in the Neo4j Browser when prepending a query with `EXPLAIN`. Using one of the Neo4j client drivers you can access this information in the [`ResultSummary` object](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/result-summary.js~ResultSummary.html) (JavaScript driver doc is linked for example).

Comment: Hi Willian, thanks for proposing EXPLAIN. I tried it and the problem I found out with it is that it's not accurate. I don't know why the query which results in no record in my database will always show `two estimated rows` in EXPLAIN's plan. But in PROFILE, it'll accurately show that the query doesn't return any records, but the problem is that it'll run the query.